# Gerrit Local setup for UI issue

Tags: gerrit

I am trying to setup Gerrit to develop new feature. I have installed all the required software as per the Gerrit offical documents.

Followed link: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/dev-eclipse.html

While starting UI getting error. I have attached the error.

Note: I am using Bazel to build the project.

Below is the error.

polygerrit-ui/app/elements/admin/gr-access-section/gr-access-section_test.ts(18,1): error TS2582: Cannot find name 'suite'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jest` or `npm i --save-dev @types/mocha`.
[compile:watch] polygerrit-ui/app/elements/admin/gr-access-section/gr-access-section_test.ts(21,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'setup'.
[compile:watch] polygerrit-ui/app/elements/admin/gr-access-section/gr-access-section_test.ts(27,3): error TS2582: Cannot find name 'suite'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jest` or `npm i --save-dev @types/mocha`.

Appreciate to assist me for the same.

As per My understanding there are missing packages in My local but please help to fix those packages issue.

Comment: _"I have attached the error."_ - where? I don't see anything. (Also, please take note of [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551))

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for advice. Updated the error. Please have a look and assist. Thanks